# singularity error regressing lag in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a forecasting model where I simply regress earnings on lagged earnings

$Y_{i,t+1}=a+bY_{i,t}$ (edit: the mathematical formulas do not seem to work in so?)

Y(i,t) = a + bY(i,t-1)

Doing so gives me however the following error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

What surprises me is that I was not getting an error message when my model was larger (where I included other variables such as X(i,t). 
What can I do to solve this issue? I tried to copy my data with dput but it was too long.

How can i only paste the first 100 values of a vector?  as in dput(A[1:100,])?

```
lm(I(inc.plus1/csout)~I(inc/csout), data=df)
```

where inc.plus1 is the lagged income (lag+1) and csout are the number of shares outstanding

A represents the first 100 entries of my vector I(inc.plus1/csout):

> dput(head(A,600))
>   structure(c(NA, NA, 1.446, 0.9995, 1.999, 2.902, 3.657, 3.96875, 
>   4.10175, 4.0565, 3.44475, 5.7205, 61.93475, -3.85725, -4.5245390070922, 
>   5.62880429175694, 2.47738918119605, 2.96300124018189, 2.73025552646406, 
>   8.07212115316016, 10.5535326434138, 15.9591327947488, 1.96747660017018, 
>   2.22629738160507, 3.58404764906088, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.37888779527559, 
>   -1.41959644816633, 1.0763348800732, 2.68114979918346, 2.80325842125764, 
>   2.43790873353744, -2.15764063396585, 1.4799008091882, NA, NA, 
>   NA, 1.37544255734004, 1.9209810662425, 2.80281184257786, 4.19364769870183, 
>   4.92729231874391, 2.12704602596336, 0.595823284929961, 2.11401303299297, 
>   2.72348504284468, 2.52902356618847, 2.32582482425984, 0.346862332597876, 
>   1.82379803991995, 2.08507363127918, 5.08163579455077, 5.94934078367083, 
>   7.23445185266149, 5.8378412444986, 4.63755947383151, -2.17174787920901, 
>   1.40756281631882, -4.05886251253207, -0.0212408027324169, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, -0.479369880443708, -0.293425018839488, 0.0929350592321281, 
>   0.123835254518112, 0.12706259774046, 0.116354410972905, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.44976515683205, 
>   4.48091561842034, 4.96571829617233, 1.65772899046248, 0.680583048407414, 
>   1.98560374302681, 4.02555335612741, 4.81968688141083, 0.762689075630252, 
>   1.88469387755102, 3.33593220338983, 0.309443507588533, 3.51697478991597, 
>   2.86402247341315, 2.03178679830559, 5.51008520836107, 3.87780527915746, 
>   2.40556264606919, 5.07700077828744, 4.83989720998532, 4.53742961245445, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.98851777777778, 
>   0.0187844444444444, 0.128071111111111, 0.699172682926829, 0.907074545454545, 
>   0.795127607650579, 0.357956423686356, -0.463226859004222, 0.60042762366109, 
>   0.855410812777128, 1.70155389507976, NA, NA, NA, 6.28810975609756, 
>   5.65225290697674, 5.50109011627907, 5.46905424200278, 6.82666666666667, 
>   9.63833333333333, 8.50433333333333, 7.02166666666667, 7.61833333333333, 
>   8.26466666666667, 9.84033333333333, 9.239, 8.05, 6.783, 7.553, 
>   8.29666724227249, 11.525749819631, 14.2648420619405, 11.2771348353078, 
>   -14.1189900160153, -17.6900879135628, 14.6432951757972, 17.706462585034, 
>   NA, NA, NA, 2.54016638089795, 2.28029063187611, -1.70405905251086, 
>   -13.3982068926821, 1.08612445944267, 1.02272906761858, -4.90830977239342, 
>   4.93192336244886, 2.71279872376048, 3.58730158730159, 2.67460317460317, 
>   -14.7646639032994, -10.1970204908481, -2.43234807690238, 1.50090714167904, 
>   0.777890139686844, 1.00461845428288, -0.577281452731578, 0.916700774289767, 
>   0.693536467511796, 1.02936271521732, 0.885562723018554, 0.533956763933385, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.33737983599889, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.97118644067797, 2.74399323181049, 
>   3.00780780780781, 3.58680659670165, 2.81889504170007, 2.50917809245523, 
>   2.79962476547842, 2.3177358490566, 2.98221831785893, 3.53841135956795, 
>   4.84714071243347, 4.42075856720104, 3.43539749078812, 2.10469553058082, 
>   0.698847262247839, 1.15489967560666, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, 16.48, 23.5307692307692, 26.2953846153846, 29.1553846153846, 
>   34.8107692307692, 34.1, 31.7707692307692, 35.66, 42.6569230769231, 
>   50.8294573643411, 60.6072371486256, 71.8920605209796, 73.1694942127795, 
>   81.0144689246958, 101.277860326894, 84.9637442320369, 99.4780896110291, 
>   NA, NA, NA, 3.21418291525857, 3.47403755478572, 2.82309202411355, 
>   1.88046287028157, 2.54218477118243, 2.86466949503918, 2.7850953423992, 
>   3.71485649429788, 3.57246064220529, 3.59200878943474, 3.39917935379717, 
>   4.36734916933839, 3.47052845528455, 2.10217797766436, 2.50138966092273, 
>   2.53216008085335, 5.6740159729317, 7.12959606279318, 3.0704500763493, 
>   -9.36316494785294, 2.98453249387051, 0.15134546114962, -0.30269092229924, 
>   NA, NA, NA, 2.5918904109589, 1.72054794520548, 3.37534246575342, 
>   3.15616438356164, 2.44266666666667, 3.72987012987013, 4.66193853427896, 
>   5.6548463356974, -6.70449172576832, 5.53191489361702, 7.55555555555556, 
>   4.56737588652482, -0.699029126213592, 3.77435897435897, 5.6053580628542, 
>   8.82009465467434, 9.75106700157242, 17.3575865849202, 6.79550870390565, 
>   -10.0748330068806, 2.45326283957664, 12.7237136465324, 15.6632796497851, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.74737416450689, 3.73783734165596, 3.56847945896463, 
>   4.01606499861509, 4.31513436031426, NA, NA, NA, 1.18216666666667, 
>   1.15616666666667, 0.718833333333333, 0.846666666666667, 0.949833333333333, 
>   0.855, 0.947, 1.362, 1.29283333333333, -0.4095, -1.71166666666667, 
>   -6.73979933110368, -1.07073578595318, 0.439966555183946, 0.889597315436242, 
>   1.29455445544554, 0.888846453280844, 2.07047744964451, 1.42014282853901, 
>   -5.14692281267341, 2.76534467725315, 2.98839786207796, 2.61554688592088, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.3883876937312, 
>   0.0920378175190796, 1.80967558338076, 4.26608220425823, 4.22229845626072, 
>   8.08242880047986, -2.31627512828963, 7.1832993650083, 1.45599924522962, 
>   -1.63071337035455, 2.12153047215424, -14.241522334182, -13.2118418381361, 
>   NA, NA, NA, 115.623529411765, 210, 224.705882352941, 234.117647058824, 
>   217.714285714286, 235.555555555556, 240, 244.878048780488, 305.853658536585, 
>   316.818181818182, 346.363636363636, 419.724770642202, 467.43119266055, 
>   561.467889908257, 683.48623853211, 792.201834862385, 953.902327704245, 
>   1135.53943789665, 1172.64573991031, 854.803010181496, 1066.1084178052, 
>   1080.66637439719, 1076.95690413369, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -8.00416281221091, -10.8834412580944, 7.80989824236818, 
>   -6.48704902867715, -27.7520814061055, 4.79648473635523, 8.26732673267327, 
>   4.09595559080095, 4.86207928837189, -9.03804256745433, -3.14144062935344, 
>   0.0326826252097871, -0.859022222222222, 2.15602936527451, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, Inf, 1.16978683393883, 1.51189430424169, 
>   3.52039622666496, 3.18081603714028, 3.61737627328914, 3.10188513592364, 
>   -7.09439807225699, -3.69752722803501, 0.707971643687819, 0.327086826731375, 
>   1.23655832779557, 0.575014101013737, 0.473355975527496, -0.122513039981693, 
>   -0.851168008718768, 0.840333176705788, 0.978143386038959, 0.767234041909876, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.9974572801517, 3.81505135065159, 3.59021071115013, 
>   2.22077609062425, 1.36322005302483, 2.3571531896427, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.37809917355372, 5.96900826446281, 9.65909090909091, 
>   8.60330578512397, 12.426, 21.7577639751553, 22.3953974895398, 
>   12.6962809917355, 2.77066115702479, 5.46201232032854, 13.7374488657494, 
>   4.1607203533809, 9.63248867259607, 12.3481116584565, -16.9937258042985, 
>   9.91789166997749, 13.2756799577502, 7.46975276170437, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   0.564217391304348, -0.212196078431373, 0.0218077803203661, 1.11794583661086, 
>   0.440747736316973, 0.363348739557059, 0.641371480161689, 1.61685900721797, 
>   NA, NA, NA), class = "AsIs")

and B:  I(inc/csout)

> dput(head(B,600))
>   structure(c(NA, NA, 1.6175, 1.446, 0.9995, 1.999, 2.902, 3.657, 
>   3.96875, 4.10175, 4.0565, 3.44475, 5.7205, 61.93475, -4.37702127659574, 
>   -5.48471405481619, 5.62880429175694, 2.48174176657021, 2.85056176051437, 
>   2.67146609592373, 7.95068353136579, 10.4269755112345, 15.9375059090479, 
>   1.96710464127044, 2.22664817849489, 3.33193683532066, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.46958661417323, 
>   3.21177447300029, -1.28516110058166, 1.0933050087961, 2.73595610276559, 
>   2.99856886650604, 2.66279506915451, -2.03313196852743, 1.54029613242514, 
>   NA, NA, 1.00559289855816, 1.37544255734004, 1.9209810662425, 
>   2.80281184257786, 4.19364769870183, 4.92729231874391, 2.12704602596336, 
>   0.595823284929961, 2.11401303299297, 2.79331431759097, 2.4658012212017, 
>   2.32582482425984, 0.346862332597876, 1.82379803991995, 2.08507363127918, 
>   5.71682560206885, 5.63252814515248, 6.95230192325872, 5.36379165580937, 
>   4.63755947383151, -2.23752373944775, 0.801826142613582, -4.05886251253207, 
>   -0.0212111270744482, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.0609118506239777, -0.46619168322258, 
>   -0.273575584586673, 0.0868731271713617, 0.121252977886906, 0.126940380912401, 
>   0.116359932757648, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.295874906555075, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.71176375317173, 3.44976515683205, 4.48091561842034, 
>   1.65520964549217, 1.65772899046248, 0.680583048407414, 1.98560374302681, 
>   4.02555335612741, 4.50134453781513, 0.771768707482993, 1.87830508474576, 
>   3.31905564924115, 0.308403361344538, 3.49909705036452, 2.85647576798639, 
>   2.02752629476767, 5.49992524792771, 3.86932091296348, 2.40325224792595, 
>   4.50212922173275, 2.72935574693607, 4.27727254986144, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.189564444444444, 
>   -1.98851777777778, 0.0187844444444444, 0.112452682926829, 0.651501818181818, 
>   0.916795915967128, 0.794619441852948, 0.35890755018202, -0.473067607413648, 
>   0.627831250675921, 0.749854780188053, 1.53659424970853, NA, NA, 
>   5.64291158536585, 5.99563953488372, 5.65225290697674, 5.26390820584145, 
>   5.243, 6.82666666666667, 9.63833333333333, 8.50433333333333, 
>   7.02166666666667, 7.61833333333333, 8.26466666666667, 9.84033333333333, 
>   9.239, 8.05, 6.783, 7.82559143498532, 8.25334112069262, 11.5059848406901, 
>   14.2409094021776, 11.2229529423791, -13.903429300047, -17.9612973562279, 
>   14.619387755102, 17.706462585034, NA, NA, 2.478958140989, 2.18773270954903, 
>   2.18862560772722, -1.69130819883693, -13.3982068926821, 1.07011419816462, 
>   1.02272906761858, -4.90830977239342, 4.93192336244886, 2.72619047619048, 
>   3.58730158730159, 2.49220723035908, -14.3167028199566, -10.2029468004578, 
>   -2.79564571994062, 1.0112571815929, 0.781369908886687, 1.00884137370567, 
>   -0.577493454139731, 0.929452560968677, 0.701576822662082, 1.03605050601517, 
>   0.8831933500736, 0.536452684873194, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, 0.492431541310724, 6.37958532695375, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.18508474576271, 1.9678510998308, 2.43498498498498, 
>   3.00329835082459, 3.58538211954771, 2.81853600059939, 2.51332082551595, 
>   2.81547169811321, 2.32570467867258, 2.98696865802967, 3.53706989369607, 
>   4.81367137790562, 4.3791117807647, 3.42566215683504, 2.10174099052259, 
>   0.698447811272854, 1.15344409599431, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, 14.96, 16.48, 23.5307692307692, 26.2953846153846, 29.1553846153846, 
>   34.8107692307692, 34.1, 31.7707692307692, 35.66, 42.9875968992248, 
>   50.9162913495884, 60.8719388550928, 73.0775328999524, 75.8763564616902, 
>   81.3488525672775, 101.094264996704, 84.6151321188249, 99.3965234503116, 
>   NA, NA, 2.3167169493513, 2.94633564772966, 3.08802835253036, 
>   2.72227364294659, 1.88046287028157, 2.54218477118243, 2.86466949503918, 
>   2.7850953423992, 3.71485649429788, 3.8251978743918, 3.59200878943474, 
>   3.45198192946663, 4.8729674796748, 3.45141240082874, 2.10217797766436, 
>   2.71891375276011, 2.53216008085335, 5.6740159729317, 7.12959606279318, 
>   3.25700635087106, -9.72848624269758, 2.98453249387051, 0.15134546114962, 
>   -0.30269092229924, NA, NA, 2.53928767123288, 2.5918904109589, 
>   1.72054794520548, 3.37534246575342, 3.072, 2.37922077922078, 
>   3.39479905437352, 4.66193853427896, 5.6548463356974, -6.70449172576832, 
>   5.53191489361702, 7.55555555555556, 4.68932038834951, -0.738461538461539, 
>   3.79185986604843, 5.57274273187322, 8.79127611345953, 9.6938568354379, 
>   17.2664485641585, 6.76008236653106, -10.0433576656954, 2.44686800894855, 
>   12.7916783806579, 15.9669198174039, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.89339789933161, 
>   4.54057279236277, 3.04295028677116, 3.52709814421568, 3.94625587429463, 
>   0.843121058173297, NA, NA, 1.16633333333333, 1.18216666666667, 
>   1.15616666666667, 0.718833333333333, 0.846666666666667, 0.949833333333333, 
>   0.855, 0.947, 1.362, 1.29283333333333, -0.4095, -1.71739130434783, 
>   -6.73979933110368, -1.07073578595318, 0.441442953020134, 0.874917491749175, 
>   1.15237157924115, 0.816345803596724, 2.04858840018688, 1.40567608276299, 
>   -5.14637884112347, 2.72871855038456, 2.91316668996454, 2.59330191769775, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.880985426787, 
>   9.24615559858754, 0.0919749573136027, 1.81008766936127, 4.28461978273299, 
>   4.25916740682639, 8.24690457134787, -2.3184854446709, 7.19083897445574, 
>   1.46494850253928, -1.64066137408225, 2.12416777231924, -14.2285966776933, 
>   -13.1682814768967, NA, NA, 121.211764705882, 115.623529411765, 
>   210, 224.705882352941, 227.428571428571, 211.666666666667, 217.435897435897, 
>   228.292682926829, 244.878048780488, 285, 316.818181818182, 349.54128440367, 
>   419.724770642202, 467.43119266055, 561.467889908257, 683.48623853211, 
>   788.224554997718, 947.416137805984, 1123.31838565022, 1157.59185480301, 
>   851.035698545615, 1060.4997807979, 1083.99296394019, 1079.33010136624, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.07169287696577, 
>   -8.00416281221091, -10.8834412580944, 7.80989824236818, -6.48704902867715, 
>   -27.7520814061055, 2.01320132013201, 4.82440240172199, 3.09241756831886, 
>   4.76328138092844, -8.83881012865689, -3.3861849659924, 0.0263111111111111, 
>   -0.84864238294285, 2.13807997770656, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   Inf, 1.13667965939339, 1.16978683393883, 1.51189430424169, 1.93641281650334, 
>   3.18037779732132, 3.60374959261304, 2.95168386947919, -7.1346652146591, 
>   -3.73879239931005, 0.618398531789007, 0.302060049537848, 1.15002820202747, 
>   0.574163266612055, 0.472550297072245, -0.122848990949101, -0.853532127125251, 
>   0.849206303333824, 0.831485168572279, 0.722226135762859, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, 4.87792789880837, 4.00254595667558, 3.88103599648815, 
>   3.94239575801398, 2.22077609062425, 1.36361444621245, 2.33424853766265, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.1797520661157, 1.37809917355372, 
>   5.96900826446281, 9.65909090909091, 8.328, 12.8633540372671, 
>   21.9853556485356, 22.1177685950413, 12.6962809917355, 2.75359342915811, 
>   4.94607660840461, 12.5518178729188, 4.10974995804665, 8.56844305120167, 
>   11.0425844346549, -16.8586942126871, 9.88777396355955, 13.2233035244608, 
>   7.5351552135845, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.47473913043478, 0.508901960784314, 
>   -0.0619107551487414, 0.0142787579128741, 1.07581896303132, 0.445689416361701, 
>   0.34090023049512, 0.649568445989942, 1.70371965372768, NA, NA
>   ), class = "AsIs")

Comment: Where's the code itself?

Comment: Re `dput`, could do `dput(head(df, 100))`

Comment: Does `csout` contain the value `0`?

Comment: csout should only contain positive values larger than 0, or NA's

Comment: There's no problem with the example data set: `lm(A ~ B)` works.

Comment: as i'm posting the code i can already see the big Inf.. Looks like i need to investigate further how i got an Inf

Comment: there is one entry where csout is 0 and thus returns an infinite value. What surprises me however is that i could still perform the regression before.